# Date input on UI Grid

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I have an AngularJS ui-grid for displaying a few fields including a date. The date comes from the server with the following format: 2018-01-31.
On the column definitions I have something similar to:

```
.columnDefs = [
...
      { name: 'startDate', displayName: 'Start Date', width: 170, enableHiding: false, cellTemplate: dateCellTemplate},
     ];
```

I've already added `type: 'date'` and `cellFilter: 'date:\'yyyy-MM-dd\''`, none of them have worked.

The template has just a date input like this:

```
const dateCellTemplate = '<div><input type="date" ng-model="MODEL_COL_FIELD" ng-change="grid.appScope.saveEdit(row)"></div>'
```

And whenever I receive the server response, my js console shows me the following error.

```
Error: [ngModel:datefmt] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/ngModel/datefmt?p0=2018-01-24
```

Comment: when you get back the response from the server are you converting it to a javascript date object using `new Date(your date here)`

Comment: No, I'm just using the data as is (string)

Comment: It sorted the problem, I cannot understand why an input would request an object rather than a string, but anyway it is sorted. Please se it as an answer and I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the model to a `Date` object before using it. Use

```
new Date(your date here);
```

This is because you're using the input type `Date` and angular expects a date type rather than string.